# 30 coin flips, what is $\mathbb{P}(\text{at least } k \text{ are }H \text{, and at least } k \text{ are T})$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-distribution

This is my attempt at starting, am I going in the right direction? -

We know at least $k$ are H, so the probability of $k$ being H is

$\begin{pmatrix} 30\\k \end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2^k} \frac{1}{2^{30-k}}= \begin{pmatrix} 30\\k \end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2^{30}}$

Now $k$ of the 30 flips have been taken up, so out of the remaining $30-k$ flips, we need $k$ to be T, and the probability of this is:

$\begin{pmatrix} 30-k\\k \end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2^{30}}$

So multiplying should give the result?

Have I thought about this correctly?

Comment: So, this iis just the probability that the number of Heads is $≤15$, yes?  Why do you say $k<15$?

Comment: Regardless, it all comes down to the probability of getting exactly $15$, which is a simple binomial calculation.

Comment: @lulu no sorry $k$ is an arbitrary constant that is less than $15$, I’ve removed this condition from the question now since it is irrelevant what $k$ is

Comment: So $k$ is a fixed number? So, then just sum the probabilities up to $k$.

Comment: @lulu sorry I don’t understand why we would need to sum the probabilities up to $k$? Do you mean sum the binomial probabilities (for each $i=1,...k$)? Surely if at minimum $k$ out of the 30 flips are H and at minimum $k$ are T then doing this sum wouldn’t help? Unless I’ve misunderstood?

Comment: Say $k=2$.  Then you have a success if you have $0$, $1$, or $2$ Heads so you must sum those cases.

Comment: "*So multiplying should give the result?*"  No.  No.... No!  You may have heard in passing somewhere that the probability that event $A$ occurs and also $B$ occurs is written as $\Pr(A\cap B)$ and can be simplified as $\Pr(A\cap B) =\Pr(A)\cdot \Pr(B)$.  That is wrong!  That is **only** allowed when $A$ and $B$ are independent events.  The events described here, "flipping at least $k$ heads" and "flipping at least $k$ tails" are most certainly not independent.  They are very much dependent.  Take for trivial example $k=30$.  It is possible to flip $30$ heads.  It is possible to flip $30$ tails

Comment: It is *not* possible to simultaneously flip $30$ heads and $30$ tails in only $30$ flips total.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of exactly $j$ heads in $30$ flips is
$$
\binom{30}{j}\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^{30}
$$
hence for any fixed $k\in\{0,...,15\}$, the probability that in $30$ flips you get at least $k$ heads and at least $k$ tails is
$$
\sum_{j=k}^{30-k} \binom{30}{j}\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^{30}
=
\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^{30}\left(\sum_{j=k}^{30-k}\binom{30}{j}\right)
$$
where the lower bound $j=k\;$is to guarantee at least $k$ heads, and the upper bound $j=30-k\;$is to guarantee at least $k$ tails.

By symmetry, the result can be simplified to
$$
\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^{30}
\left(\left(2\sum_{j=k}^{14} \binom{30}{j}\right)
+
\binom{30}{15}\right)
$$
Equivalently, by complementary counting, the result can be rewritten as
$$
1-\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^{29}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{30}{j}\right)
$$
which requires less work if $k$ is small.

Comment: Thank you very much, is there anyway in which we can simplify the sum of those binomial coefficients? Of course if $k=0$ we could just apply the binomial theorem, but I’m not sure if that could help trying to simplify the sum?

Comment: If $k$ is small, you can do the complement and subtract from $1$.